# How to convert NSManagedObject Array into String Array - Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, swift3, uisearchbar

I want to convert NSManagedObject Array into String Array for Search purposes. (I don't want to use predicates)

The search would be performed on an attribute "Notes" of an entity "Documents"

```
var documents: [NSManagedObject] = [] // data is saved in this after fetch request !
var filtered = [String]()
var  dataa = [String]()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    //the line below is not working 
//        dataa =  [String(describing:documents)]


    filtered = dataa.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        //          let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)


        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = true;

    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

fetched data is stored into documents (NSManagedObject) through this function & it is called on viewDidLoad()

```
func fetchDocuments() {
    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Documents")

//PLEASE TELL ME SOME CODE TO SAVE ALL FETCHED NOTES IN "dataa" SO THAT I CAN PERFORM FILTERING. 
// It would be done like obtaining value from the nsmanagedobject via (abc.value(forKeyPath: "note") as? String)!

    do {
        documents = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        let errorDialog = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Failed to save! \(error): \(error.userInfo)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        errorDialog.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        present(errorDialog, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that  `dataa = documents.value(forKeyPath: "note")` should work.

Comment: where should i paste the above code ?

Comment: You're trying to go a hard way. I strongly advise you to filter ```NSManagedObject``` array using predicates and then show string property of ```NSManagedObject``` in your views.

Comment: @shmidt Thanks ! I am looking for predicates now... :)